# Reuse builder step across different builders

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, query-builder, builder

For a C# data access layer I want to use the builder design pattern to build queries against DBContexts (for greater flexiblity in the buisiness layer but without direct access to IQueryable) in a fluent API way.

Many queries have a similar structure:

```
AccountQueryBuilder.GetAccounts().ForClient("clienta").WithBalanceOver(1943.4).QueryAsync();
/// ...
ContractQueryBuilder.GetContracts().ForClient("clienta").ExpiresAfter(2020-04-01).QueryAsync();
```

Here the `ForClient(string)` is reused between different builders. How would I design the builder, so that I can reuse different builder steps across different builders, by still restricting the next available builder steps and not having to implement `ForClient(string)` for each builder again? There will be multiple reusable steps in different combinations

Currently I have something like this:

```
class BuilderA : IBuilderReady, IBuilderStepA, IBuilderStepB, IBuilderStepC, IReusableStepA<IBuilderStepA>
{
    IBuilderStepA ReusableA() {/*Don't want to reimplement in every builder*/}
    IBuilderStepB A() {...}
    IBuilderStepC B() {...}
    IBuilderReady C() {...}
    IEnumerable<EntitySomething> Query() {...}
}
```

Comment: Whilst this might seem like a neat idea (and it is!), I would recommend against this approach for 2 reasons.   1) You are basically trying to write a new 'SQL' style language that will be very much restricted and no-one else will understand, and. 2) your time would be better suited to understanding how EF (and SQL) works, which will improve your code and give you transferable skills.

Comment: Why not declare the method in a parent class, and let the builders inherit from this class? If this is not what you want; i see no other option than using interfaces in much the same way you are using them now.